# Hide title of navigation bar without removing it

Tags: iphone

I have a customized navigation bar with a image background. I do want to show the title on the background but I need its text for the back button in the next view.

`self.title=@""` will not put (naturally) in the back button the previous title.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Based on the suggestion of pheekicks, I found a tip to do it:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,  nil]];
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to switch between view controllers, and you want to hide title text of navigation bar, that still appear back button, in root view controller, you should override this method:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.navigationItem.titleView = m_anyViewYouWant;
}
```

This is OK!

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly old post. But I got around this problem by setting the title in the viewWillDisappear method, so it does not show when the view is displayed, but shows in subsequent views back button.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"mytext", nil)];

}
```

Comment: Just commenting myself, that needs to go in pair with setting the title to "" when the view appears.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
self.titleView.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not work, self.navigationItem.titleView.hidden = YES either

Comment: It should work. In what context are you using self? Does it definitely refer to your instance of the UINavigationItem class?

Comment: I put "self.titleView.hidden = YES;" here :

-- code --

/* .h */
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#define FILE_NAME_HEADER @"header.png"
@interface Header : UINavigationBar <UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
}
@end

/* .m */
#import "Header.h"
@implementation Header
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
 self.textView.hidden = YES;
 [[UIImage imageNamed:FILE_NAME_HEADER] drawInRect:rect];
}
@end

-- end code --

But I obtain "something not a structure of union".

Comment: self.titleView.hidden = YES;

I mean

Comment: `UIViewController` does not have a property called, `titleView`.

Answer (score -3):

I'm using this line to hide the navigation bar on `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
```

Comment: We want to hide the title bar without hiding the navigation bar.