# UINavigation bar's title and rightbar button is displayed in all the view controllers I have

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationbar

I have an app with a storyboard and 2 viewcontrollers. I have created the Navigation controller programatically through Appdelegate. And I have set the title as "Screen1" in the `viewDidLoad()` of Viewcontroller1 and I have added a rightbar button.

Now, my problem is, when I click on the rightbar button, viewcontroller2 is displayed with the title set to "Screen1" and the rightbar button also appears.

Note: In the ViewController2, I did not set any title and I did not add any bar button.

My code:

**AppDelegate.m: -> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions():**

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];    
VC1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.VC1];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

**ViewController1.m -> didViewLoad():**

```
self.navigationItem setTitle:@"first slide"];

UIBarButtonItem *goto2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Goto to 2" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(GotoSlide2)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:goto2];


-(void) GotoSlide2
{
ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide navigation bar in ViewController2, write below code in `viewDidLoad` of ViewController2 :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
```

it will hide `navigationBar` for ViewController2.

Edit:
To hide title write below code in `viewDidLoad` of ViewController2:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

OR

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

From this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/2461163/5575752

To hide right bar button:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"";
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: no, I dont want to hide the navigation bar. I want the title to be empty and the rightbar button should not be dispalyed in the ViewController2.

Comment: Ok. To hide the title & rightbar button this is fine. But I want to know why it is displaying in the ViewController2. I am creating the navigation controller and setting its rootviewcontroller in code, not using storyboards. I want to know, is this the way it will behave as I have done everything in code?

Comment: yes, all view controller have it's navigation controller and navigation bar from app delegate, as you set navigation controller as root view controller@vinoth

Comment: I am fine that all the viewcontrollers are taking the Navigation controller and bar from AppDelegate, but why the title and the buttons are there in all the ViewControllers as I added those in ViewController1 alone? @ Ronak

Comment: The navigation bar is always present and is managed by the navigation controller itself, which updates the navigation bar using the content provided by the view controllers on the navigation stack. read more  at: [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/)